# Sideloading Universal Windows Phone 8.1 Company App on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-mobile, side-loading, certificate

First i installed the AET, then i try to install a Company App over email.

### Results

- **Windows Phone 8.1 .appx fails on Lumia 930 (factory new)** - After pressing "Install" the dialog disapears and nothing happens. It is almost the same problem, described in this question: [Cannot install company app on windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416437/cannot-install-company-app-on-windows-phone-8/15420912#15420912)
- **Windows Phone 8.1 .appx succeed on Lumia 630 (developer mode)** - App is finally installed and listed.
- **Windows Phone 8 .xap succeed on Lumia 930 (factory new)** - App is finally installed and listed.

### Environment

OS: *Windows 8.1 Enterprise*

IDEs installed: *Visual Studio Community 2013 & 2015*

IDE used: *Visual Studio Community 2015*

VS Project details: *Apache Cordova, WinJS, angularjs*

Certificate: *Company certificate from symantec, received from extern company*

My MS Dev Account: *Nothing i do pay for*

### Signing

The signing process succeded without any error

I used this command:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\Tools\MDILXAPCompile\BuildMDILAPPX.ps1" -appxfilename "C:\SignApps\CordovaApp.Phone_1.0.0.0_arm.appx" -pfxfilename "c:\SignApps\Certificate.pfx" -password ***** -inputFolder "C:\SignApps\input" -outputfolder "C:\SignApps\output"
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the app via your company hub?

Comment: The Installation didn't work over MDM either. A company hub app does not exist for now.